# Boolean to integer in php

Tags: php, checkbox, int, boolean, logic

I am currently using checkboxes in a form and want to save the checkbox value into a database column of type int. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this. I have already tried casting the variable to a `(int)` but this has not done anything for me yet.

```
HTML: <input name='active' id='active' ng-model='formData.active' ng-init='formData.active=true' type="checkbox"> Active </br>


PHP:
$active = (int) $_POST['active'];
echo $active;
echo $_POST['active'];

Output:
0
true
```

Note: I am trying to implement this without an awful if statement or switch.

Comment: the name in form is `sticky` and you are accessing it using `$_POST['active']` !!

Comment: @Subhanker that was just me derping updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_POST` variable for the checkbox will only be set if the checkbox is checked, so you can use something like this:

```
$active = isset($_POST['active']) ? 1 : 0;
```

I suspect that you're getting the string "true" rather than a boolean "true", in which case you can use a similar construct:

```
$active = $_POST['active'] === "true" ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I am not using 'vanilla' post requests, so this won't work i already tried ;)
1,false

Comment: @MattMc please see my latest edit. Also, could you tell us what the result of `var_dump($_POST['active'])` is? I'm guessing that it's the string "true".

Comment: lol check the last posted answer, i just derped. thanks anyways. indeed it was a string

Answer (score 0):

solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288171/3923450 should work,

but if you are looking for an inbuilt function, try

```
intval
```

Answer (score 0):

add an value attribute in input tag

```
<input name='active' value='1' ...>
```

Now it should work the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around in the PHP manual the following code can be found:

```
filter_var('FALSE', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, array('flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#118356

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, your input in HTML is "sticky" and in PHP you test "active".
But anyway, try in PHP following test:

```
if (isset($_POST['sticky']) and ($_POST['sticky']=='on')) $active=1;
else $active=0;
```

Comment: It has already been edited 13 minutes ago i.e 12 minutes before your answer.